# Haskell function that parses an email address

Tags: email, parsing, haskell

Is there a Haskell function that parses an email address in a standard format? For example:

```hs
parseEmailAddress "Jon Doe<jon.doe@mail.com>"
```

would return something like:

```hs
Address (Just "Jon Doe") "jon.doe@mail.com"
```

I could not find a function that does this in the `mime-mail` package.

Comment: I am one of the downvotes. I also voted to close, for the exact same reason: library recommendations requests are off-topic here, because the answer is so likely to change over time. If it does get closed, it will show you text to this effect; it is a bummer that the text isn't shown until then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Here is what I wrote.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}

module Email (parseEmailAddress) where

import           Text.Parsec (parse)
import           Text.Parsec.Rfc2822 (NameAddr(..), name_addr)
import           Network.Mail.Mime (Address(..))
import           Data.Text (pack)
import           Data.List (elem)

mapMaybe :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
mapMaybe _ Nothing = Nothing
mapMaybe f (Just a) = Just (f a)

-- | Given a string email address, spits out an Address record
parseEmailAddress :: String -> Maybe Address
parseEmailAddress str =
  case parse name_addr "" addr of
    Left _ ->
      Nothing
    Right (NameAddr { nameAddr_name, nameAddr_addr }) ->
      Just (Address (mapMaybe pack nameAddr_name) (pack nameAddr_addr))
  where
    -- Standardize the email address
    addr = if '<' `elem` str then str else "<" ++ str ++ ">"
```

Then, the function would work as follows:

```hs
parseEmailAddress "johndoe@example.com"  -- Just (Address Nothing "johndoe@example.com")

parseEmailAddress "John Doe <john.doe@example.com>" -- Just (Address (Just "John Doe") "johndoe@example.com")

parseEmailAddress "johndoe" -- Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work:

```
parseEmailAddress xs =
  case break (== '<') of
    (mail, "") -> Address Nothing mail
    (name, mail) -> Address (Just name) (init (tail mail))
```

This assumes that the name does not include the `<` character.